# Read, modify and write STDF file - Python

Tags: python, automated-tests

I see there is a Python library (pystdf) to read/parse the STDF file. Is there any such function/library to write the STDF file?

Requirement is to implement following in Python:

1. Read data from STDF file
2. Add missing data to it
3. Write data back to STDF file

Would appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73410796/4603318

Comment: Are you changing data throughout the STDF or just in MIR or other headers?

Comment: Hi @Chris94,
The idea is to find which data is missing in the STDF file and then write to it.
So data is to be changed throughout the STDF. 
You can add your comments even if it is just related to MIR or other headers. 
Would be a good starting point :)