# how to convert stdf to csv using python

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me how to write python code to convert STDF to csv file. I am trying using [pystdf](https://github.com/cmars/pystdf) module but not successful in converting.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pystdf


def convert_stdf_to_csv(input_file, output_file):
  
   stdf = pystdf.STDF(input_file)

   records = [record for record in stdf.records()]

   df = pd.DataFrame(records)

   df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)


input_stdf_file = "input.stdf"

output_csv_file = "output_file.csv"

# Convert STDF to CSV
convert_stdf_to_csv(input_stdf_file, output_csv_file)
```

Comment: What specifically is not successful? Could you provide a [mre]? Related: [How to transfer data from STDF file to Pandas dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72897110/10197418)

Comment: You don't need to drag in the enormous pandas module just to write a CSV file.  Those are easy.  Have you printed the records to see what it is delivering to you?

Comment: Thankls for quick comment @TimRoberts i know the content of the stdf , it will  have test name ,  limits, units and device data of  ICs

Comment: No, you don't know what the Python variables look like.  List of strings?  List of ints?  If you know what the data structure is, it's trivial to turn it into a CSV.