pystdf IO method TypeError
I'm trying to convert stdf file from 93k tester to pandas using STDF2DataFrame method.
here is my code:
import sys, os
from pystdf.Importer import STDF2DataFrame
import pystdf.V4 as V4
import pandas as pd



fin = 'Ex.stdf'
dfs= STDF2DataFrame(fin)

I'd tried different methods but I always got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Temp\module2.py", line 10, in <module>
    dfs= STDF2DataFrame(fin)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\Importer.py", line 73, in STDF2DataFrame
    data = ImportSTDF(fname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\Importer.py", line 42, in ImportSTDF
    p.parse()
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 190, in parse
    self.parse_records(count)
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 162, in parse_records
    fields = recParser(self, header, [])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 36, in newRecordParser
    fields.append(action(*args))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 202, in <lambda>
    return lambda self, header, fields: parseFn(header, fieldType)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 238, in <lambda>
    "Vn": lambda header, fmt: self.readVn(header)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 115, in readVn
    vn.append(self.vnMap[fldtype](header))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pystdf\IO.py", line 246, in <lambda>
    0: lambda header: self.inp.read(header, 1),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: read expected at most 1 argument, got 2


Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72897110/how-to-transfer-data-from-stdf-file-to-pandas-dataframe-in-python

If not I recommend looking at this wrapper that aims to assist in the conversion https://github.com/Semi-ATE/Metis (there seems to be a lot of nuance, ie. byte order, when it comes to STDF files).
